# Skip Custom Zuul Filter

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-zuul

Can we skip all the filters except route filter for a particular request ?

Lets say, I have 5 routes(Micro serviceas) defined and 5 pre-filters. I want to skip these pre-filters(I don't even want to execute shouldFilter()) for one of the routes. Can I achieve this by any configuration in application.properties or application.yml?

Comment: set zuul.ignored-services to a list of service ID patterns.

Comment: if we include the property zuul.ignored-service complete service is getting ignored I don't want to exclude from zuul. I want to exclude only one Filter.

Answer (score 0):

I would say no you can't. Why do you need that?

The purpose of filter is to filter request at specific point in life cycle (pre/route/post/error filters), they are defined in certain way and if you want to skip some filtering on the same path/request use `shouldFilter()` method.

And if you don't want to filter specific path/request, just don't create any filter for it.
Hope that helps.